# Find limit for $n*C^n$ when $|C|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}{n{C^n}}$ when: $|C|<1$

I want to use the squeeze theorem so I bounded it from below with: $C^n\to 0$

But I can't find the upper bound.

Comment: You could consider the closely related function $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ given by $f(x)=x\cdot C^{x}$, and take its limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$.  You can rearrange the function and use l'Hospital's Rule.  Your result will then apply to the original limit.

Comment: Take limit at the function $\frac{n}{C^{-n}}$

Comment: Let $|C|=1+t$. Note that by the binomial theorem,  if $n\ge 2$ we have $(1+t)^n\ge 1+nt+(n)(n-1)t^2/2\gt n(n-1)t^2/2$. Now you should be able to Squeeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know thats an old post but here is another solution

Bernoulli inequality states that:
$$\boxed{(1+\alpha)^n \geq n(1+n\alpha) \quad \forall r>-1, \text{ } n\in \mathbb{N^*}}$$

---

Given than $C<1$:

Let: $C = 1+\alpha \iff \alpha > -1$.

Also $n \in \mathbb{N} $

---

Therefore the contraints of Bernoulli inequality are satisfied and you can re-write your limit as:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} nC^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(1+\alpha)^n \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} n(1+n\alpha) = +\infty$$

Hence, by the squeeze theorem:
$$ nC^n  \to +\infty $$

Answer (score 2):

If $C=0$ there is nothing to do.

Otherwise, ${1 \over |C|} > 1$ and from
the first 3 terms of the binomial expansion we get
${1 \over |C|^n} = (1+({1 \over |C|}-1))^n \ge 1 + n ({1 \over |C|}-1) + { 1\over 2} n(n-1) ({1 \over |C|}-1)^2$, and
so
$n|C_n| \le {n \over 1 + n ({1 \over |C|}-1) + { 1\over 2} n(n-1) ({1 \over |C|}-1)^2}$. Since the right hand side $\to 0$, we have the desired result.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the power of $n$ you did there?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You care about $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Right. I got why if the right side goes to 0 it's solved. What I didn't get are the steps leading to the final inequality.

Comment: Sorry, it used the first 3 terms of the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$, where $x = {1 \over |C|} -1$ (which is $>0$).